# How to make one column fixed and the other one scrollable and make it normal column flow on small screens bootstrap 5?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

How to make one column fixed and the other one scrollable, and make it normal column flow on small screens? so every column is full screen and normal flow?

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12  fixed-top ">
      <h2>Fixed</h2><br> It is a good platform to learn programming. It is an educational website. Prepare for the Recruitment drive of product based companies like Microsoft, Amazon, Adobe etc with a free online placement preparation course. The course focuses
      on various MCQ's & Coding question likely to be asked in the interviews & make your upcoming placement season efficient and successful. Also, any geeks can help other geeks by writing articles on the GeeksforGeeks, publishing articles follow few
      steps that are Articles that need little modification/ improvement from reviewers are published first. To quickly get your articles reviewed, please refer existing articles, their formatting style, coding style, and try to make you are close to
      them. Adobe etc with a free online placement preparation course. The course focuses on various MCQ's & Coding question likely to be asked in the interviews & make your upcoming placement season efficient and successful. Also, any geeks can help
      other geeks by writing articles on the GeeksforGeeks, publishing articles follow few steps that are Articles that need little modification/ improvement from reviewers are published first. To

    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12 offset-sm-6 h-100">
      <h2>Scrollable</h2><br> It is a good platform to learn programming. It is an educational website. Prepare for the Recruitment drive of product based companies like Microsoft, Amazon, Adobe etc with a free online placement preparation course. The course
      focuses on various MCQ's & Coding question likely to be asked in the interviews & make your upcoming placement season efficient and successful. Also, any geeks can help other geeks by writing articles on the GeeksforGeeks, publishing articles follow
      few steps that are Articles that need little modification/ improvement from reviewers are published first. To quickly get your articles reviewed, please refer existing articles, their formatting style, coding style, and try to make you are close
      to them. Adobe etc with a free online placement preparation course. The course focuses on various MCQ's & Coding question likely to be asked in the interviews & make your upcoming placement season efficient and successful. Also, any geeks can help
      other geeks by writing articles on the GeeksforGeeks, publishing articles follow few steps that are Articles that need little modification/ improvement from reviewers are published first. To It is a good platform to learn programming. It is an educational
      website. Prepare for the Recruitment drive of product based companies like Microsoft, Amazon, Adobe etc with a free online placement preparation course. The course focuses on various MCQ's & Coding question likely to be asked in the interviews &
      make your upcoming placement season efficient and successful. Also, any geeks can help other geeks by writing articles on the GeeksforGeeks, publishing articles follow few steps that are Articles that need little modification/ improvement from reviewers
      are published first. To quickly get your articles reviewed, please refer existing articles, their formatting style, coding style, and try to make you are close to them. Adobe etc with a free online placement preparation course. The course focuses
      on various MCQ's & Coding question likely to be asked in the interviews & make your upcoming placement season efficient and successful. Also, any geeks can help other geeks by writing articles on the GeeksforGeeks, publishing articles follow few
      steps that are Articles that need little modification/ improvement from reviewers are published first. To It is a good platform to learn programming. It is an educational website. Prepare for the Recruitment drive of product based companies like
      Microsoft, Amazon, Adobe etc with a free online placement preparation course. The course focuses on various MCQ's & Coding question likely to be asked in the interviews & make your upcoming placement season efficient and successful. Also, any geeks
      can help other geeks by writing articles on the GeeksforGeeks, publishing articles follow few steps that are Articles that need little modification/ improvement from reviewers are published first. To quickly get your articles reviewed, please refer
      existing articles, their formatting style, coding style, and try to make you are close to them. Adobe etc with a free online placement preparation course. The course focuses on various MCQ's & Coding question likely to be asked in the interviews
      & make your upcoming placement season efficient and successful. Also, any geeks can help other geeks by writing articles on the GeeksforGeeks, publishing articles follow few steps that are Articles that need little modification/ improvement from
      reviewers are published first. To It is a good platform to learn programming. It is an educational website. Prepare for the Recruitment drive of product based companies like Microsoft, Amazon, Adobe etc with a free online placement preparation course.
      The course focuses on various MCQ's & Coding question likely to be asked in the interviews & make your upcoming placement season efficient and successful. Also, any geeks can help other geeks by writing articles on the GeeksforGeeks, publishing
      articles follow few steps that are Articles that need little modification/ improvement from reviewers are published first. To quickly get your articles reviewed, please refer existing articles, their formatting style, coding style, and try to make
      you are close to them. Adobe etc with a free online placement preparation course. The course focuses on various MCQ's & Coding question likely to be asked in the interviews & make your upcoming placement season efficient and successful. Also, any
      geeks can help other geeks by writing articles on the GeeksforGeeks, publishing articles follow few steps that are Articles that need little modification/ improvement from reviewers are published first. To It is a good platform to learn programming.
      It is an educational website. Prepare for the Recruitment drive of product based companies like Microsoft, Amazon, Adobe etc with a free online placement preparation course. The course focuses on various MCQ's & Coding question likely to be asked
      in the interviews & make your upcoming placement season efficient and successful. Also, any geeks can help other geeks by writing articles on the GeeksforGeeks, publishing articles follow few steps that are Articles that need little modification/
      improvement from reviewers are published first. To quickly get your articles reviewed, please refer existing articles, their formatting style, coding style, and try to make you are close to them. Adobe etc with a free online placement preparation
      course. The course focuses on various MCQ's & Coding question likely to be asked in the interviews & make your upcoming placement season efficient and successful. Also, any geeks can help other geeks by writing articles on the GeeksforGeeks, publishing
      articles follow few steps that are Articles that need little modification/ improvement from reviewers are published first. To It is a good platform to learn programming. It is an educational website. Prepare for the Recruitment drive of product
      based companies like Microsoft, Amazon, Adobe etc with a free online placement preparation course. The course focuses on various MCQ's & Coding question likely to be asked in the interviews & make your upcoming placement season efficient and successful.
      Also, any geeks can help other geeks by writing articles on the GeeksforGeeks, publishing articles follow few steps that are Articles that need little modification/ improvement from reviewers are published first. To quickly get your articles reviewed,
      please refer existing articles, their formatting style, coding style, and try to make you are close to them. Adobe etc with a free online placement preparation course. The course focuses on various MCQ's & Coding question likely to be asked in the
      interviews & make your upcoming placement season efficient and successful. Also, any geeks can help other geeks by writing articles on the GeeksforGeeks, publishing articles follow few steps that are Articles that need little modification/ improvement
      from reviewers are published first. To It is a good platform to learn programming. It is an educational website. Prepare for the Recruitment drive of product based companies like Microsoft, Amazon, Adobe etc with a free online placement preparation
      course. The course focuses on various MCQ's & Coding question likely to be asked in the interviews & make your upcoming placement season efficient and successful. Also, any geeks can help other geeks by writing articles on the GeeksforGeeks, publishing
      articles follow few steps that are Articles that need little modification/ improvement from reviewers are published first. To quickly get your articles reviewed, please refer existing articles, their formatting style, coding style, and try to make
      you are close to them. Adobe etc with a free online placement preparation course. The course focuses on various MCQ's & Coding question likely to be asked in the interviews & make your upcoming placement season efficient and successful. Also, any
      geeks can help other geeks by writing articles on the GeeksforGeeks, publishing articles follow few steps that are Articles that need little modification/ improvement from reviewers are published first. To It is a good platform to learn programming.
      It is an educational website. Prepare for the Recruitment drive of product based companies like Microsoft, Amazon, Adobe etc with a free online placement preparation course. The course focuses on various MCQ's & Coding question likely to be asked
      in the interviews & make your upcoming placement season efficient and successful. Also, any geeks can help other geeks by writing articles on the GeeksforGeeks, publishing articles follow few steps that are Articles that need little modification/
      improvement from reviewers are published first. To quickly get your articles reviewed, please refer existing articles, their formatting style, coding style, and try to make you are close to them. Adobe etc with a free online placement preparation
      course. The course focuses on various MCQ's & Coding question likely to be asked in the interviews & make your upcoming placement season efficient and successful. Also, any geeks can help other geeks by writing articles on the GeeksforGeeks, publishing
      articles follow few steps that are Articles that need little modification/ improvement from reviewers are published first. To It is a good platform to learn programming. It is an educational website. Prepare for the Recruitment drive of product
      based companies like Microsoft, Amazon, Adobe etc with a free online placement preparation course. The course focuses on various MCQ's & Coding question likely to be asked in the interviews & make your upcoming placement season efficient and successful.
      Also, any geeks can help other geeks by writing articles on the GeeksforGeeks, publishing articles follow few steps that are Articles that need little modification/ improvement from reviewers are published first. To quickly get your articles reviewed,
      please refer existing articles, their formatting style, coding style, and try to make you are close to them. Adobe etc with a free online placement preparation course. The course focuses on various MCQ's & Coding question likely to be asked in the
      interviews & make your upcoming placement season efficient and successful. Also, any geeks can help other geeks by writing articles on the GeeksforGeeks, publishing articles follow few steps that are Articles that need little modification/ improvement
      from reviewers are published first. To

    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/plugins.js"></script>
  <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```